# Warning : The referenced component 'NuGet.Core' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, warnings

I am working on a developed desktop application in Visual Studio 2010. Till yesterday everything was fine but from today as soon as I open the project in Visual Studio it is giving me warning,"The referenced component 'NuGet.Core' could not be found". I searched in Solution Explorer and found that in the Project-> References, NuGet.Core with an exclamation mark. Is something got deleted or corrupted I don't know. Please Help!! I am not able to find the reason behind this. Searched for the solution but no success.[Image:This is what I got while searching in Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS4Hp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclamation mark means that the project has lost the location of the reference, but it knows it should be there. If you manually delete the reference (right click on the component and then select delete) and then re add it (project -> add reference -> then find the file location [you should not need to re add it using Nuget]) to you project it should get your project working again.

With regard to why this is happening, something may have changed somewhere that caused VS to lose the reference. This could be the location of the reference, or source control, or something else. Often I am unable to find the reason for this.