# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting below error in one of my ASP.NET Web API Project.

> Could not load file or assembly '**Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime**,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

I've tried to redirect the assembly bindings like below which didn't work:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Also, properties for given dll reflects the correct information:

[image]

I have checked the public key of the dll using "**sn.exe**" which is exactly same to what is showing in the error.

I have tried following other steps as well:

- Cleaning up the project > building again
- Restart Visual Studio
- Restart Machine
- Checking the **bin** folder for given dll (Yes, it exists!)

Nothing of the above has worked so far. Please share your thoughts if anybody has had the same issue ever.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: **Backup your project**. Run this command: `Install-Package Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime -Version 2.3.2`

Comment: Or **change**: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />` to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.3.2.0" />`

Comment: Is it working??

Comment: let me try this @vanloc

Comment: @vanloc: didn't work... same error

Comment: Try to clean Debug and Release folders in your solution. Then remove and add `Rest.ClientRuntime` again.

Comment: You tried to check all method in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies. Hope it help. Before I had same your issues. I only update my .dll to the latest version. Or change option: `Copy Local` from `True` to `False`.

Comment: @vanloc: reinstallation didn't work... let me check the link you're referring

Comment: Have you checked to see it the project has lost the reference to the DLL? See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138638/warning-the-referenced-component-nuget-core-could-not-be-found/43140443#43140443

Comment: @vanloc: done true/false... didn't work

Comment: @Alex: tried doing that Alex.. no luck!

Comment: @SunnySharma Were you able to get it to work ?

Comment: @SunnySharma I have the same problem here.